# Number of real roots of $p_n(x)=1+2x+3x^2+....+(n+1)x^n$ if $n$ is an odd integer

Tags: polynomials, roots

> If $n$ be an odd integer. Then find the number of real roots of the polynomial equation $p_n(x)=1+2x+3x^2+....+(n+1)x^n$

$$
p_n(x)=1+2x+3x^2+....+(n+1)x^n\\
x.p_n(x)=x+2x^2+....nx^n+(n+1)x^{n+1}\\
p(x)[1-x]=1+x+x^2+....+x^n-(n+1)x^{n+1}\\
p(x)=\frac{1+x+x^2+....+x^{n}}{1-x}-\frac{(n+1)x^{n+1}}{1-x}=\frac{x^{n+1}-1}{x-1}\frac{1}{1-x}-\frac{(n+1)x^{n+1}}{1-x}\\
=\frac{x^{n+1}-1-(n+1)(x-1)x^{n+1}}{-(x-1)^2}=\frac{x^{n+1}-1+(n+1)x^{n+1}-(n+1)x^{n+2}}{-(x-1)^2}\\
=\frac{(n+2)x^{n+1}-(n+1)x^{n+2}-1}{-(x-1)^2}=\frac{1-(n+2)x^{n+1}+(n+1)x^{n+2}}{(x-1)^2}=0\\
\implies \boxed{(n+2)x^{n+1}-(n+1)x^{n+2}=1}
$$

I think I am stuck with my attempt, how can I find the real solutions ?

Comment: Uhhh ... did you forget to post something? This post seems half-finished. What is your question, for that matter?

Comment: @Eevee Trainer pls check i hv edited  OP

Comment: The last expression is not correct; at least, the $1$ is no more here

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici thanx . pls check hope i have corrected it.

Comment: This is correct now. Thanks for fixing it. Now, follow Gerry Myerson's hit.Cheers :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$
p(x)=1+2x+3x^2+\ldots+(n+1)x^n;\\
xp(x)=x+2x^2+3x^3+\ldots+(n+1)x^{n+1};\\
(1-x)p(x)=1+x+x^2+\ldots+x^n-(n+1)x^{n+1}=\frac{1-x^{n+1}}{1-x}-(n+1)x^{n+1}\\
=\frac{1-x^{n+1}-(1-x)(n+1)x^{n+1}}{1-x}=0.\\
\Rightarrow1-x^{n+1}-(1-x)(n+1)x^{n+1}=0
$$
Note that $x=1$ is clearly not a solution of the original equation. As a result, the above equation is actually equivalant to your original equation, apart from having an extra root $x=1$.

Here is the equation we are trying to solve:
$$
1-x^{n+1}-(1-x)(n+1)x^{n+1}\equiv (n+1)x^{n+2}-(n+2)x^{n+1}+1=0\\
\Leftrightarrow(n+1)x^{n+2}=(n+2)x^{n+1}-1
$$
Since the original equation has no roots for $x\geq 0$, we now focus on the case $x<0$. When $x<0$, LHS is decreasing toward $-\infty$; RHS is increasing towards $\infty$. LHS>RHS for $x=0$. This tells us that the original equation has only one root.

Comment: I understand ur first statement, no solutions for $x\geq0$ as $p(x)>0$. But could u pls explain the later part more.

Comment: so u mean .. as LHS is strictly decreasing towards $-\infty$ and RHS is strictly increasing towards $+\infty$, both curves should intersect at some point, thus have only one root, right ?. But, how can we find the value of the real root ?

Comment: You can find it using WolframAlpha. It's value should tend to $1$ as $x \to \infty$. However, you know, algebraic equation of degree $5$ or higher doesn't have a formula.

Answer (score 5):

You have found that $p(x)$ is a rational function. It is zero if and only if its numerator is zero. Its numerator is a polynomial of the form $Ax^{n+2}+Bx^{n+1}+C$, where $A,B,C$ are constants. The derivative of that numerator is of the form $Dx^{n+1}+Ex^n=x^n(Dx+E)$ for some constants $D,E$. It's easy to see how many real roots that derivative has. Then Rolle's Theorem tells you something about how many real roots the original numerator has. Can you fill in the details and draw a conclusion?

Comment: could u please add more details as I am having trouble following ur hint.

Comment: You'll have to do better than that. Where are you having trouble? Let's start at the beginning. Do you know what a rational function is?

Comment: I guess not. OK, a rational function is a quotient of two polynomials. Any other part of my answer giving you trouble? I can't help you, if you won't tell me what's wrong.

Comment: extremely sorry for the delay. I understand what a rational function is. and here it is of the form $Ax^{n+2}+Bx^{n+1}+C$ which can be seen from my final equation. And its derivative $Dx^{n+1}+Ex^n=x^n(Dx+E)$.So far its clear. And rolles theorem tells u that if the function has two roots then there must be atleast one stationary point where the derivative is zero in between them. But, how do I use it here to reach the desired conclusion ?

Comment: $A=n+1,B=-n-2,C=1,D=(n+1)(n+2),E=-(n+1)(n+2)\implies E=-D$. $p(x)=Ax^{n+2}+Bx^{n+1}+C$ and $p'(x)=Dx^{n+1}+Ex^n=x^n(Dx+E)$.Now, $p'(x)=0\implies x=0$ or $x=-E/D=-1$, right ?.Now how do I use Rolle's theorem ?

Comment: OK, so, the derivative has only two real zeros. So, how many can the function have? And what can you say about where they must be?

Comment: Thats whr my confusion is. If we have 2 real zeros for the derivative, i guess the function can have two min. maxima together ?. And how do I make use of Rolle's theorem here ?